# Get the maximum repeated row per day in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get maximum repeated rows per day. I am providing a sample data and expected result based on it

My Table looks like

[image]

```
SELECT TYPE, DAY, COUNT(1) FROM table1 
GROUP BY TYPE, DAY
ORDER BY DAY



TYPE    DAY  COUNT(1)
A       1    4 
B       1    2
A       2    5
B       2    7
```

expected output

```
TYPE    DAY  COUNT(1)
A       1    4 
B       2    7
```

I am trying to take maximum repeated rows per day based on count.
Thanks in advance, Any help much appreciated

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d9001b680ac9fe57a6394a682800f077

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `row_number()`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT TYPE, DAY, COUNT(*),
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DAY ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM table1 
      GROUP BY TYPE, DAY
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY DAY;
```

If you only wanted the type, that is called the `MODE`.  You can get that using `STATS_MODE()`:

```
select day, stats_mode(type)
from table1
group by day;
```